# Both Google Play App Signing Certificate and Upload Certificate created Same SHA1 key in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, sha1

Recently i opted Google Play console  App Signing feature into my existing app using "Export and upload a key from a Java keystore" option in Release Management->App Signing.

I had followed the first 3 steps and uploaded the "App Signing Private key".

After this step, I got the "App Signing Certificate " and "Upload Certificate" having the same SHA1 Fingerprint Certificate for both.

Does anybody face this issue in Google Play console? TIA

Comment: Signing keys cannot change for existing apps. I'm not sure what you expected to happen? Can you make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: My "App Signing Certificate " and "Upload Certificate" have also same SHA1 (google play services are not working). And I am trying to figure out that is it the main source of problem or not. Please inform us if you find any solution or this is not an anomaly and everything works fine..?

Comment: @AhmetHayrullahoglu we can change the Upload certificate key.

Comment: I solved the problem and still using same "App Signing Certificate " and "Upload Certificate" which was not a source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The App Signing Certificate and Upload Certificate have same SHA1 when we tried to upload the keystore of an existing app in the play store.

Solution Which worked for me:(To change the SHA1 in Upload Certificate)

-->Create a new keystore file using the exisitng keystore.

-->Upload the new key into the "App Signing" section under keystore management.

It will take 24-48hrs to reflect the new SHA1 in Playstore console.

*contact google play store customer support for more details regarding this.

*Note: If you are releasing test build through play store for testers, use the test SHA1 key(if app is having any google services which requires) which is completely different from the upload certificate in the console.